# CSS flush image?

Tags: css

I'm working on this site here: http://seobeaver.ca/what-we-deliver/

I got the product image to line up with the green section previously using a negative padding-bottom value here:

```
img.img-with-animation {
opacity: 0;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: -7px;
```

Suddenly that no longer works and there is a space between the image and the next section ruining the effect.

help?

Comment: You should consider turning this into a jsFiddle even though it's already answered because your link might go down, change or what not and this becomes a useless question and answer for the SO database except for the fact that paddings can't have negative values!

Answer (score 4):

Negative padding values are not valid, but negative margin values are. 
So you can change `padding-bottom` to `margin-bottom`, and keep negative value.

```
img.img-with-animation {
opacity: 0;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: -7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-top: -7px` on the green div.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to address this by removing the cause of the problem. Thus:

```
img.img-with-animation {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

By default, images are set to `vertical-align: baseline`, which leaves a gap beneath them. (The image aligns with the baseline of any text that might sit beside it, with space below for descenders). You can change this by using `vertical-align: bottom;`.